# why socket is ready to read only after thousands of iterations?

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I am writing my http server. I use select function and see that socket is ready to write any time, but can be read only after thousands of iterations. If I use select(Max+1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, NULL), I do not have such problem. Why it is ready to read only after so many iterations?

```
int iteration = -1;
while (true)
{
    iteration++;
    FD_ZERO(&rfd);
    FD_ZERO(&wfd);
    FD_SET(listeningSocket, &rfd);
    for (std::set<int>::iterator Iter = servingSockets.begin(); Iter != servingSockets.end(); Iter++)
    {
        FD_SET(*Iter, &rfd);
        FD_SET(*Iter, &wfd);
    }
    int Max = std::max(listeningSocket, *std::max_element(servingSockets.begin(), servingSockets.end()));
    res = select(Max + 1, &rfd, &wfd, NULL, NULL);
    if (res <= 0)
        continue;

    if (FD_ISSET(listeningSocket, &rfd))
    {
        if ((newSocket = accept(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&listeningSocketAddr, (socklen_t *)&listeningSocketAddr)) < 0)
            continue;
        fcntl(newSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
        servingSockets.insert(newSocket);
    }

    for (std::set<int>::iterator Iter = servingSockets.begin(); Iter != servingSockets.end();)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(*Iter, &rfd))
        {
            std::cout<<"iter in loop: "<<iteration<<std::endl;
            int bytes_recvd = recv(*Iter, request, request_buffer_size - 1, 0);
            if (bytes_recvd < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "error recv\n");
                shutdown(*Iter, SHUT_RDWR);
                close(*Iter);
                servingSockets.erase(*Iter);
                continue;
            }
            request[bytes_recvd] = '\0';
            parse_http_request(request, &req);
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(*Iter, &wfd) && req.path[0] != '\0')
        {
           
            send(*Iter, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<h1><a href=\"\">external</a><br><a href=\"internal\">internal</a></h1>", 122, 0);
            shutdown(*Iter, SHUT_RDWR);
            close(*Iter);
            Iter = servingSockets.erase(Iter);
            continue;
        }
        Iter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is not really helpful, because it contains lots of irrelevant things. A proper [mcve] would be better, including of course the client side if that is relevant. Also, what do *you* think that "ready to read" means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A socket will *always* be writable, unless you fill up its buffers.

So `select` will return immediately for every call, with all the sockets marked as writable.

Only add sockets to the write-set when you actually have something to write to them. And once you have written all you need, then remove them from the set and don't add them back (until the next time you need to write to the socket).

---

When you don't use the write-set, then `select` will simply not return until there's a socket active in the read-set.